# Guess the puzzle described below

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Who has trapped me
inside my home
Goes around the world
oftenly alone.
In the last year plan
Was that place so good
Got her name
From some kind of wood
Almost with all of them
She shares her self
Except two of them
Where we cannot help
One of them
I put in my dish
All teams should guess this
That’s all I wish.